# GTK disappears while in sudo mode

Tags: 14.04, themes, gtk, mate, engine

I want to know how is possible to enable gtk (gtk2 engine) in this case for sudoers? When I start an application using gksudo or it run elevated, the application doesn't benefit from the engine while if I am normal user everything is okay.

Does it have something related with /usr/share/themes and people who use it?

Ubuntu Mate Edition 14.04

Comment: Do you have a screen shot of what is happening?